# How to make one container have rounded Corners and not the other Container

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I am trying to achieve the design show in the image but I can't because gaps show between the two containers when I try to round ones corners,

How do I achieve the design in the screenshot I want the corners to overlap the other Container now have white space when I try to round the corner?

```
[![return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: \[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
              //     color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,

              ),
        ),][1]][1]
    Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CupertinoButton(
              onPressed: () {
             
              },
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.person),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 12,
                  ),
                  Text('Profile'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            CupertinoButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // dbhandler.signOut();
              },
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.info),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 12,
                  ),
                  Text('About app'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            CupertinoButton(
              onPressed: () {
                dbhandler.signOut();
              },
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.logout),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 12,
                  ),
                  Text('Sign out'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

),
);

Comment: Please add your full code

Comment: please add the image of what you are getting using your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have white space because a `Column` lays out its children in a sequential vertical pattern. It cannot be used to lay one child on top of the other (unless you apply transforms, but that defeats the purpose).

This UI can be made using a `LayoutBuilder` to get `constraints` so that we can properly place our header, body, and image properly inside a `Stack`.

Output:

[image]

Let's define some sizes. Feel free to calculate this as needed by your application. First, let's set a size for our header.

```
final headerSize = constraints.maxHeight * .25;
```

Second, let's determine the radius of our body's card:

```
const radius = 24.0;
```

Third, let's determine the size of our image:

```
const imageSize = 128.0;
```

Next, we'll use a stack and our determined values to place and draw the elements in the correct order. We also apply the values defined above.

```
final myCard = LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    /// Determine your image size; could be a factor of
    /// [constraints.maxWidth].
    const imageSize = 128.0;

    /// Determine the border radius of the body.
    const radius = 24.0;

    /// 
    final headerSize = constraints.maxHeight * .25;

    return Stack(
      children: [
        /// Header height includes radius to avoid empty corners.
        Positioned(
          height: headerSize + radius,
          top: .0,
          left: .0,
          right: .0,
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(imagePath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: const Text(
              "Header",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        /// The body is drawn after the header. It has rounded
        /// [topLeft] and [topRight] corners.
        Positioned.fill(
          top: headerSize,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(radius),
                topRight: Radius.circular(radius),
              ),
            ),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: const Text("Body"),
          ),
        ),

        /// The image is added last, so that it can drawn last (on top
        /// of other elements).
        Positioned(
          top: headerSize - imageSize / 2.0,
          left: constraints.maxWidth / 2.0 - imageSize / 2.0,
          child: Container(
            width: imageSize,
            height: imageSize,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.cyan,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(imageSize / 2.0),
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: const Text("Image"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

We also want the outer part to have a border radius, and a background color:

```
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 48.0),
  color: Colors.deepPurple,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
    child: myCard,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the use of Layout builder?

Comment: Yes, look into `MultiChildLayoutDelegate`.